# .submenu class missing in output from wp_nav_menu

Tags: theme-development, themes

I Am Developing A Custom Theme. I have registered nav menus as you can see below

```
 register_nav_menus(
            [
                'hub_header_menu' => __('Header Menu', 'HUB_WP'),
                'hub_footer_menu' => __('Footer Menu', 'HUB_WP'),
            ]
        );
```

Code Of Printing Menus

```
<div class="header-desktop">
            <?php wp_nav_menu([
                'theme_location' => 'hub_header_menu',
            ]); ?>
</div>
```

I have Some Menu Items With Submenu But the problem is that the ".sub-menu" class is missing in submenus and they are printing as simple menu item.Like Code In Code Below, the "Sample" Page Is Sub item of "Home" but it is printed as simple menu items instead of submenu item.

[image: HTML output]
[image: Menu Items]

I want to get .sub-menu class to style it. If I remove theme_location than it works properly but whenever i put theme location, it starts causing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on looking at the output HTML i'd have guessed this was because `wp_nav_menu` was using the fallback cb to render a `wp_page_menu`, the clue was the output of `page_item` classes instead of `menu-item` classes.

From the docs for [`wp_nav_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) args:

> **fallback_cb** callable|false
> If the menu doesn't exist, a callback function will fire.
> Default is 'wp_page_menu'. Set to false for no fallback.

Which may have been an indicator that your nav menu registration code was not being registered on the right action, usually we hook these onto `init` in the theme's functions file.